# Algorithm that sorts elements within range of values into clusters?

Tags: algorithm

Essentially I want to take a list of things like...

```
a 345
b 762
c 983
d 425
e 45
...
```

and given a maximum distance, create clusters for each element containing other elements within that range. For example, if I specified the maximum distance above to be 300 the clusters would be...

```
a 345
d 425
e 45

b 762
c 983

c 983
b 762

d 425
a 345

e 45
a 345
```

Constraints wise, I'm reading entries in a file, which is common with the work I'm doing. As such, I generally focus my algorithms on doing work as it reads entries, rather than reading everything in the file, storing it in some convenient structure, and then doing work on it. Anyway, storing the entries from the file and then performing a sort based on those values, then just going through the sorted list and doing appropriate output is something I'm trying to avoid.

I've done some layman brainstorming, but before I spend lots of time doing a thorough analysis I feel like I've seen this somewhere or that there is an algorithm very similar to this. I'm not asking for someone to come up with an algorithm unless you feel so inclined, just wondering if there are any existing ones that solve this problem or one very similar to it.

Thanks.

Comment: The only way you can avoid storing it in the memory is if you either: a. Are willing to have a margin of mistake. b. Know the order (or can predict the order) of the elements. c. You don't need an absolute order

Comment: To be more specific, I was more trying to imply that one of the steps required is to read those values in, so not to assume that they are already stored in memory. I thought it was important to consider because you could get work done while reading the values in rather than waiting them to all be stored in memory, which may or may not matter depending on the nature of the algorithm.

Comment: Why do you need to avoid storing all the data in memory at once? It seems like you would have to either know the order(sort them and then go over the list in sorted order) or have some kind of data structure that stores what groups exist in memory, at which point you are going to pretty much be keeping the whole list in memory

Comment: As for clustering you have to actually compare elements against each other (or store them in a dimensional tree for querying later on) it's hardly possible to do anything useful (except tree build-up e.g.) before/unless all elements are loaded in memory. And reading elements from disk on demand (repeatedly, that is) would be even worse, as i/o is usually a/the major speed bottleneck. For nearest-neighbor-like problems (as this one is) you'd usually want to go with a dimensional tree (BKTRee, KDTree, VPTree, …) for their excellent querying speed.

Comment: I don't have to avoid storing all of the data in memory at once. I am saying that there is a step that involves reading data from a file, so possibly performing work while reading data in is something to consider. Thanks Regexident for the info, will try out your answers later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another possible **flood fill algorithm** using some **modified binary search** to reduce the amount of required comparisons:

```
Pseudo-code:
def clustersWithinRange(values, distance): //Should run in O(n log n)
    sortedValues = values.sorted()
    valueCount = values.len()
    clusters = Array()

    cachedLower = 0
    cachedUpper = values.len
    cachedValue = null

    for i in range(0, valueCount):
        value = sortedValues.get(i)
        if (cachedValue == value): //duplicate value, no need to calculate twice
            clusters.add(clusters.get(i).copy()) //simply clone last cluster or nop if no duplicate clusters wanted
        else:
            lower = sortedValues.binaryBoundSearch(values, value, distance, cachedLower, i, LowerBoundMatchFlag)
            upper = sortedValues.binaryBoundSearch(values, value, distance, cachedUpper, valueCount, UpperBoundMatchFlag)
            clusters.add(sortedValues[lower:upper+1])//add sublist within (and including) lower...upper to clusters
            cachedLower = lower
            cachedUpper = upper
    return clusters

    def withinDistance(valueA, valueB, distance):
        return abs(valueA - valueB) <= distance

    def binaryBoundSearch(values, value, distance, low, high, searchFlag):
        // Possible values of searchFlag:
        // "LowerBoundMatchFlag" to get the leftmost found match.
        // "UpperBoundMatchFlag" to get the rightmost found match.
        if (high < low):
            return -1 // not found
        mid = low + ((high - low) / 2)
        matchPosition = -1
        aValue = values[mid]
        if (withinDistance(aValue, value, distance)):
            matchPosition = mid
            displacement = (searchFlag == LowerBoundMatchFlag) ? -1 : 1
            if (mid > low && mid < high && withinDistance(values.get(mid + displacement), value, distance)):
                newLow = (searchFlag == LowerBoundMatchFlag) ? low : mid + displacement
                newHigh = (searchFlag == LowerBoundMatchFlag) ? mid + displacement : high
                matchPosition = binaryBoundSearch(values, value, newLow, newHigh, searchFlag)
        else:
            flag = compare(aValue, value)
            if (flag < 0): // current position too far left
                matchPosition = binaryBoundSearch(values, value, mid + 1, high, searchFlag)
            else if (flag > 0): // current position too far right
                matchPosition = binaryBoundSearch(values, value, low, mid - 1, searchFlag)

        return matchPosition
```

Comment: Ended up basically using this. There were a few extra constraints I didn't mention for the sake of simplicity, but they ultimately just involved low order work.